# Dependabot can't find my GAR Maven Packages (404)

Tags: google-artifact-registry, dependabot

I am trying to set up Dependabot to automatically check my private registries for updates. I'm successful with authentication, and dependabot looks at my xml for my package, but when it tries to find the JAR's it fails with a 404.
This is my dependabot configuration:

```yaml
version: 2
registries:
  artifact-registry:
    type: maven-repository
    url: "https://{region}-maven.pkg.dev/{project}/{repo}/"
    username: "_json_key_base64"
    password: ${{ secrets.ARTIFACT_REGISTRY_READER_B64 }}
  maven-central:
    type: maven-repository
    url: "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/"
updates:
  - package-ecosystem: "maven" # See documentation for possible values
    directory: "/" # Location of package manifests
    schedule:
      interval: "daily"
    registries:
      - artifact-registry
      - maven-central
```

But in the logs, I am getting this:

```
404 https://{region}-maven.pkg.dev:443/{project}/{repo}/com/{org}/{repo}/1.24-SNAPSHOT/{repo}-1.24-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

and if I visit it directly (after authenticating with user and pass) i get the following:

```
{
"error": "Requested entity was not found."
}
```

For all my other packages (that arent in a private repo), dependabot can find the jars just fine when looking at "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/".

TLDR: Why can't dependabot find my JAR's for a private, maven repository hosted on Artifact Registry?

Answer (score 0):

Based on this documentation on [Cloud Build 4xx client errors](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/troubleshooting#4xx_client_errors), this could indicate that the build request is not successful presumably by fault of the user sending the request.

Please check the build logs if it contains more information regarding the error. Here are some of the common causes:

- The source location you specified does not have anything new to commit and the working tree is clean. In this case, check your source code location and try building again.
- Your repository does not contain a [build config file](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/build-config). If this is the case, upload a build config file to your repository and run the build again.
- You've specified an incorrect trigger ID.
- You have recently added a new repository after installing the Github app, and Cloud Build does not have permissions to access the new repo. If this is the case [connect your new repository to Cloud Build](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/automating-builds/create-github-app-triggers).
- You need to grant another permission to the service account.

If the aforementioned steps didn't work or were not applicable, you may file a bug through the [Google Cloud issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) so that Google Cloud engineers could take a look at this. This doesn't have a specific ETA but you can keep track of its progress once the ticket has been created.